# How to serialize multiple models with one Serializer using DjangoRestFramework?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have these Models all of which have PointField:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    category = models.ForeignKey(PlaceCategory, verbose_name='Категория')
    ...
    point = geomodels.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    ...


class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Адрес')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, verbose_name='Город')
    ...
    point = geomodels.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...


class Meeting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participating_meetings')
    ...
    point = geomodels.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

In project I have `/points` API url. By this url I want to return filtered set or all the points to show them on map.
I checked DRF documentation, there is example how to build Serializer for one Model, but how do I build the API view for these multiple models?

Comment: post your best shot at making a serializer. (not related: why are you using a third party point field instead of geodjango?)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of use case is typical of where you'd need to drop the default auto generated things (serializer / view) and roll your own. I would gather the data by myself, run them through a `PointSerializer` - might be optional - which would inherit from `Serializer` and return the result.

Comment: Can you please give a snippet of such `PointSerializer`?